# Excel Macro/VBA copying rows depending on values matched

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a excel file that will create a sheet based on some criteria.

I have a Row I will select based on a X to look in a column
The column C4 to C10 then will look for one of the following three criteria:

- **Test**:
  If Test is found then depending if it is at the top of the column, rows 2:19 in sheet 1 should be copied to the new created sheet first empty row what can be checked in that sheet Row C
  If it is at the bottom then the rows rows 2:19 from sheet 2 need to be copied to the first empty row what can be checked in that sheet Row C
- **Closed**:
  If Closed is found then rows 2:19 in sheet 3 first and afterwards sheet 4 should be copied to the created sheet
- **Open**:
  If Open is found then rows 2:19 in sheet 5 first and afterwards sheet 6 should be copied to the created sheet

The above should all be paste in a new created sheet that should have a sub sequential number from the previous created sheet.

[Table checking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUPlQ.png)

Code using to locate X:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ' Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    FindString = "X"
    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
    With ActiveSheet.Range("C2:N2") 'searches all of column A
        Set Rng = .Find(what:=FindString, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        lookat:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            Application.Goto Rng, True 'value found
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing found" 'value not found
        End If
    End With
    End If
    End Sub
```

Hope all is clear and you can help me with this.

I have tried the following code and can successfully locate "X":

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ' Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    FindString = "X"
    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
    With ActiveSheet.Range("C2:N2") 'searches all of column A
        Set Rng = .Find(what:=FindString, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        lookat:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            Application.Goto Rng, True 'value found
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing found" 'value not found
        End If
    End With
    End If
    End Sub
```

But can't copy form a different sheet using the following code:

```
Sub SearchForString()   
   Const ASearchRow = 2
   Const BSearchRow = 2
   Dim CopyToRow As Integer
   Dim rng1 As Range
   Dim rng2 As Range
   Dim cell As Range
   Dim found As Range
   
   Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet2 (row counter variable)
   CopyToRow = 2
   
   Set rng1 = Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(ASearchRow, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(ASearchRow, 1).End(xlDown))
   Set rng2 = Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(BSearchRow, 2), ActiveSheet.Cells(BSearchRow, 2).End(xlDown))
   
   For Each cell In rng1
   
   Set found = rng2.Find(what:=cell, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
   
   If Not found Is Nothing Then
   
   cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & CopyToRow)
   
   CopyToRow = CopyToRow + 1
   
   End If
   
   Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: your test conditions says if it is at the top copy row2:19 sheet1 and if bottom row2:19 sheet2 then your image attachment shows there are two test values in the list, so your data can have test at the top or test at the bottom or test at the top and bottom? whats the desired result if there are two test values?

Comment: Hi k1dr0ck,

Both are valid. Depending on the position (top or bottom of the row) a different set of rows are copied in to the new created sheet.

Comment: what is your sheet name format and number?

Comment: also what do you mean by `copied to the new created sheet first empty row what can be checked in that sheet Row C`

Comment: Sheet name will be OPS-OSL-0001 and will be created sub sequential
Colomn C of the new to be created sheet will have text to check the last row.

Comment: when you say rows 2:19 do you mean entire rows 2 to 19 or A2:A19? if entire rows are to be copied you cannot choose a column to paste in because the entire row will be pasted

Comment: Yes, I mean A2:A19 but complete rows

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub addNewSheet()
    Dim latestSheetNum As Integer
    Dim newSheetName As String
    Dim nws As Worksheet, msht As Worksheet
    Dim FindString As String, firsttest As Boolean
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, nwslastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range, j, k
    
    Set msht = ActiveSheet
    firsttest = False
    FindString = "X"
    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
        Set rng = msht.Range("C2:N2").Find(what:=FindString, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            lastRow = msht.Cells(Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp).Row
            'loop found column starting at row 4
            For i = 4 To lastRow
            If msht.Cells(i, rng.Column) = "TEST" Then
                If firsttest = False Then
                    Set nws = NewNumsht()
                    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A19").Copy nws.Range("C1")
                    nwslastRow = nws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    firsttest = True
                 Else
                    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A19").Copy nws.Range("C" & nwslastRow)
                    nwslastRow = nws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                 End If
            ElseIf msht.Cells(i, rng.Column) = "CLOSED" Then
                  For j = 3 To 4
                  Sheets("Sheet" & j).Range("A2:A19").Copy nws.Range("C" & nwslastRow)
                  nwslastRow = nws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                  Next j
            ElseIf msht.Cells(i, rng.Column) = "OPEN" Then
                  For k = 5 To 6
                  Sheets("Sheet" & k).Range("A2:A19").Copy nws.Range("C" & nwslastRow)
                  nwslastRow = nws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                  Next k
            End If
            Next i
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing found" 'value not found
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Function NewNumsht() As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Dim latestSheetNum As Long
    Dim latestSheetName As String
    Dim NewSheetNum As Long
    Dim newSheetName As String
    
    ' Get the latest sheet number and name
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Left(ws.Name, 8) = "OPS-OSL-" And IsNumeric(Right(ws.Name, 4)) Then
            If CLng(Right(ws.Name, 4)) > latestSheetNum Then
                latestSheetNum = CLng(Right(ws.Name, 4))
                latestSheetName = ws.Name
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
    
    ' Create the new sheet with an incremented number
    NewSheetNum = latestSheetNum + 1
    newSheetName = "OPS-OSL-" & Format(NewSheetNum, "0000")
    Set newSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    newSheet.Name = newSheetName
    
    ' Return the new sheet
    Set NewNumsht = newSheet
End Function
```

Comment: Thnx!!
it seems to be exactly what I will be needing accept that i cannot get the code working.
new in this.
If i copy it in it does create the new sheet but does not copy the select to the created sheet.

Comment: @CruzzerNpc-stack1202 in your `Activesheet` it will look for `X` in range `C2:N2` if found then look for the values `TEST` `OPEN` `CLOSED` in the same column it was found starting at row 4 up to the last row with value, your workbook must have already sheets named `Sheet1` `Sheet2` `Sheet3` `Sheet4` `Sheet5` `Sheet6` and each of those sheets must have values in the range `A2:A19`